# Networking on Galileo Gen2: What's the MAC address?

Tags: iot, intel-galileo

I'm using the latest build of Windows IoT for the Galileo Gen2 (9600.16384.x86fre.winblue_rtm_iotbuild.150309-0310_galileo_v2) and writing Wiring applications in VS2013Pro.

I want to start building network connections, but the first parameter I need to specify is the MAC address.  The board came with a MAC printed on a sticker on the mag-jack, but did it get written to the onboard flash somewhere?  Were do I find it from inside my Wiring/IoT app?

Answer (score 0):

Ron,

You may try [logging into the device via telnet](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win8/SetupGalileo.htm) and running '[getmac](http://www.windows-commandline.com/get-mac-address-command-line/)' or '[ipconfig /all](http://idoc.vsb.cz/en/okruhy/cit/pc/sitova_pripojeni/mac_adresa/mac_adr_win7/cmd/)'.  This should give you the MAC address for your device.

Comment: I already know the MAC.  I can see it on the sticker.  I need my application to discover the MAC of whatever board it is on.  For whatever reason, it has to be specified again when opening a port.

Comment: You may be able to determine this by invoking the commands above from System.Process in your application code and parsing the output.